What is the full name of IBM CP-67/CMS' DUMPD command?
I am reading the User Guide of CP-67. Under the command DUMPD (page 373), it describes its Purpose as:

The DUMPD command prints the contents of one direct-access record,
specified by a CCHHRR address, in hexadecimal on the printer.

I am designing an operating system, and I want to add this command to my operating system. I want the full name of this command, in order to make this command more beautiful.
So, what is the full name of the CP-67/CMS' DUMPD command? Is it DUMPDATA, DUMPDASD, DUMPDIR, DUMPDEVICE or DUMPDISK?

Please address it as Humpd Dumpd, Esq.

Furthermore, Humpd would have no truck with our quibbling. “When I use a word,’ Humpty Dumpty said in rather a scornful tone, ‘it means just what I choose it to mean — neither more nor less.’

I was hoping someone would pick up on that...

I plan to make the DUMPD command of my operating system display data of disk volumes or other kinds of storage devices, in hexadecimal format, like what the DUMP command of DEC's RT-11 and OpenVMS operating systems does.

There is none. DUMPD is DUMPD.
Remember Names were the way they are. It's about being memorable, not necessary about explaining anything. People worked for years on such systems and grew with them. Also shortness was preferred over readability in all cases. See also DUMPF.

DUMPDASD,

It doesn't dump a DASD but one (or more) of its records

DUMPDIR,

There are not 'DIR's on IBM DASD disks.

DUMPDEVICE

That's what DISK DUMP is about - except it's about dumping a DISK onto another record device.

DUMPDISK?

Not really, see DUMPDASD

DUMPDATA,

Maybe, except it does not dump any data but the content of a specified record on that a DASD drive.

The workings are best imagined as picking a single punch card out of a pile of cards, printing it's content and optionally he following. Handling stacks of cards (records) is the way DASD operation originated and was designed after
Now if you really want something long, DUMPRECORD or DUMPSECTOR might work best. After all, the modern sector is what the original DASD record degenerated into. For some additional information see this answer.

The DIR of DUMPDIR is the abbreviation of the word 'DIRect' of 'direct access record'.

@YilinHuo Just keep in mind hat you're of  very different generation grown up with computers that are already fully developed. The 360 or CP-67 was created by people not born in a wold of computers restrained by limitation unimaginable for today's generation. I started out in the 1970s with those systems and had already a different background. One that was already ancient by 1980, so never look back and assume today's terminology, canon or mind set about what the objects are that get manipulated.

DUMPSECTOR is already out of date; it was arguably on the scrapheap when disks were addressed by a flat block address (LBA in the PC world, other terms in earlier systems).  But on solid state devices there's nothing whose geometry can reasonably be described as 'a sector' (just like there's no storage that is actually disc-shaped).

I just think that command names can explain something. For example, the fullname of DUMPF maybe DUMPFILE, because DUMPF is a file-related command, and F is the first character of the word 'file'. Same abbreviations also appear in LISTF and PRINTF commands. When CP/CMS becomes IBM VM/CMS, the LISTF command is renamed to LISTFILE.

Nevertheless, the question is "what is the full name of DUMPD", and the answer is "DUMPD".  There is no longer name, even if someone thinks that "DUMPD" is somehow short for something else, or it could "explain" something.  "Full names" exist only in the imagination. This answer should be the accepted one.

It's good practice for a summary of a (compound) abbreviation to expand its elements into a description. IBM certainly had very good technical authors at that time.
The DUMPD summary ('Purpose') is "The DUMPD command prints the contents of one direct-access record, specified by a CCHHRR address, in hexadecimal on the printer."
So it's reasonable to take DUMPD as trying to express 'dump direct-access record'.
And it's good that you're re-interpreting the command naming for your modern take on an operating system. Those engineers would have pounced on the technology and knowledge we now have at our disposal to strip away many of these limitations forced on them, as time and progress has shown.

But what limitations gave rise to 'DUMPD'?  'DUMPDATA', 'DUMPREC', etc., would have been equally possible, as evidenced by the existence of other 8-character commands.  I'd just assume designers like me, preferring brevity to prolixity.
